# weird argument value for Javascript function when single vs multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments

Sorry in advance if this has been asked before, but I wasn't able to find it from my searches.

output observed in developer mode for
Firefox 50.1.0
Chrome 55.0.2883.87

** maybe this is what I'm doing wrong, but don't just look at console.log in developer mode, but also click on the details of the object for that specific console.log call

I came across this code from Learning Advanced JavaScript, and I added some console.log calls to understand it better. However, the outputs for my console.log calls do not make sense to me.

I expect the output of the console.log("p00, ...) call to be the same, but the output is different depending on whether the first "return root" is commented or not.

When the first "return root" is not commented, then the console.log("p00, ...) displays an Object with a single property - it being "name". This is what I expect and makes sense to me.

When the first "return root" is commented, then the console.log("p00, ...) displays an Object with two properties - they being "name" and "city".
Why is this happening here ??

.

Below is the Javascript code:

```
function merge(root){ 
    console.log("p00, root is ", root);
    console.log("p01, arg length is ", arguments.length);
    console.log("p02, arg is ", arguments);


    // comment out this return call and see the difference
    return root; 


    for ( var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
        for ( var key in arguments[i] ) {
            root[key] = arguments[i][key]; 
        }
    }

    return root; 
} 

var v1 = {name: "John"};
var v2 = {city: "Boston"}; 
var merged = merge(v1, v2);
console.log("p03, merged is ", merged);
```

observed output in Firefox:

first return root uncommented
[first return root uncommented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCgOH.png)

first return root commented
[first return root commented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Kqc.png)

Comment: your images show the argument, root, is the *same* either way in the first console.log. only the *last* console.log changes with the //return - it will show either the unchanged or merged results, respectively, which is what you see on the right side.

Comment: Thanks goes out to @sweaver2112 and Mike C.

Comment: It was a misunderstanding on my part on how output is displayed in Firefox and Chrome.

Conclusion - for console.log("p00 ...), outputs are the same for both cases, but console provides a reference to the Object, so it will show the final state of the Object when you try to see more details regarding that Object. The JSON.stringify was a great suggestion to see a snapshot of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console provides a *reference* to the object you're logging out. That means you're seeing the state of the object *after* your function has finished running.

If you want to see a snapshot of an object's state, you could try converting it to JSON.

```js
// Be sure to open your real console for this
function reference(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  obj.b = 2;
}

function json(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  obj.b = 2;
}

reference({ a: 1 });
json({ a: 1 });
```